# If $\int_A f d \mu = \int_A g d\mu$ for continuous positive $f,g$ and a Radon measure $\mu$, is $f=g$ a.e.?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups, radon-nikodym

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ a Radon measure on $X$. If $f,g: X \to (0, \infty)$ are continuous functions such that
$$\int_A f d \mu = \int_A g d\mu$$ for all Borel subsets $A$,
can we deduce that $f=g$ almost everywhere?

(Note that in general $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for a point $x \in X$ is possible, even if $f,g$ are continuous, because a Radon measure may assign zero measure to an open subset of $X$!).

My attempt:

It is easy enough to see that $f\chi_U = g \chi_U$ $\mu$-almost everywhere for any $U\subseteq X$ compact subset $U$. Indeed, by continuity and compactness $f$ is bounded on $U$ and compact subsets have finite measure. The same can be said about precompact open sets.

However, $X$ may not be $\sigma$-finite so I don't see how to deduce that $f=g$ a.e.

Comment: Radon measure requirements are? Borel measure obviously. Inner regular for compacta? Outer regular for open? Locally finite? Texts differ....

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Borel measure, finite on compacts, outer regular on opens and inner regular on Borels.

Comment: See also (b) of proposition 2.23 in Folland's book. I think the question is a generalization of this for $f,g\in L^1_{loc}(X,\mu)=\{h: \int_K|h|d\mu<\infty \text{ for all compacts }K\}$, where $\mu$ is a Radon measure (note that the proof is essentially the same argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\{x: f(x) >g(x)\}$. If $\mu (A) >0$ then there exists a compact set $K \subseteq A$ such that $\mu (K)>0$. Now $\int_{K_N} fd\mu= \int_{K_N} gd\mu$ where $K_N=\{x\in K: f(x) \leq N, g(x) \leq N\}$. If $\mu (K_N)>0$ then  this is clearly a contradiction (since  $\int_{K_N} fd\mu> \int_{K_N} gd\mu$). Hence, $\mu (K_N)=0$ for each $N$ which shows that $\mu(A)=0$. Similarly, $\mu \{x: f(x)<g(x)\}=0$ so $f=g$ a.e.

Remark: Continuity of $f$ and $g$ is not used. Borel measurability is enough.

Comment: I think it is possible that $\int_A gd\mu=\infty$ and then your proof fails. But we can use regularity to find a compact subset contained in $A$ and then maybe we can fix the proof. So maybe topology is relevant after all?

Comment: @Andromeda I have edited my answer to take care of infinities.

Comment: The same problem still exists: $\int_A g=\infty$ and your strict inequality fails.

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: @Andromeda You are right. Regularity is needed.  I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, a more general thing holds that what I wrote in the question:

> If $\mu$ is a Radon measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space and
> $f,g: X \to [0, \infty[$ are positive continuous functions such that
> $$\int_K f d \mu = \int_K g d\mu$$ for all compact subsets $K
> \subseteq X$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere.

**Proof**: Let $A= \{f > g\}$. If $\mu(A) > 0$, inner regularity implies the existence of a compact subset $K \subseteq A$ such that $\mu(K) > 0$. Note that $f\chi_K$ and $g\chi_K$ are integrable, because these $f,g$ are bounded on $K$ and because $\mu(K) < \infty$ by definition of Radon measure. Then since $\mu(K)>0$,
$$\int_K f d \mu > \int_K g d \mu = \int_K f d\mu$$
a contradiction. Thus, $\mu\{f > g\} = \mu(A) = 0$. Similarly, $\mu\{f < g\}=0$ and thus $f = g$ $\mu$-a.e.